# Why Bootstrap 4 Navbar collapse is not working after installing carousel?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a navbar which was working nicely. It was collapsing as screen size turned smaller with the button click. After installing carousel Navbar collapse is not working. When I delete the carousel part Navbar collapse is working nicely again in small screen. I must need both working simultanously.

Why it is not working? Here is the code:

```
<!--Navigation Area-->
    <div id="navigationArea">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid logo"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Navigation Area-->

    <!--Slider Area-->
    <div id="sliderArea">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel fade-in" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./images//banner1.jpg" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./images//1386329591384banner01.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of sliderArea-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should **remove the wrapping div** around the carousel according to the docs 
[carousel/#with-indicators](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/#with-indicators)